# Alternative to virtual variables

Tags: c++, oop

I have two classes, `Base` and `Derived`. `Derived` inherits from `Base` and additionally includes several functions and variables -- therefore the need to have two separate classes. However, they do share one function, `run`.

In the example below I have to pass an argument to `run` in order to execute `read` - this argument depends on which class the object refers to. Is it possible to write a generic version of `read` such that the program automatically uses `vars_Base` or `vars_Derived` depending on which object calls `run`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
  protected:
    void read(std::vector<std::string>);

  public:
    void run(std::vector<std::string> vars) { read(vars); }
    std::vector<std::string> vars_Base;
};

void Base::read(std::vector<std::string> int_vars)
{
    for (auto int_vars_it : int_vars)
    {
        std::cout << int_vars_it << "\n";
    }
}

class Derived : public Base
{
  protected:
  public:
    std::vector<std::string> vars_Derived;
    ///Here are other functions only known to Derived, not Base
};

int main()
{
    Base b;
    b.vars_Base.push_back("aB");
    b.vars_Base.push_back("bB");
    b.vars_Base.push_back("cB");
    b.run(b.vars_Base);

    Derived d;
    d.vars_Derived.push_back("aD");
    d.vars_Derived.push_back("bD");
    d.vars_Derived.push_back("cD");
    d.run(d.vars_Derived);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass a copy of a member variable as an argument? Why doesn't the member function just use the member variable directly?

Comment: How about a protected virtual function which returns (a reference to) the vector you want to use? Or make `run` virtual and override it in the derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the result you want to get?

```
class Base
{
protected:
    using vars_type = std::vector<std::string>;

private:
    vars_type vars_Base;

protected:
    virtual vars_type& get_vars() {
        return vars_Base;
    }

public:
    void push_back(const std::string& str) {
        get_vars().push_back(str);
    }

    void run()
    {
        for (auto int_vars_it : get_vars()) {
            std::cout << int_vars_it << " ";
        }
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    vars_type vars_Derived;

protected:
    vars_type& get_vars() override {
        return vars_Derived;
    }

public:
    ///Here are other functions only known to Derived, not Base
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Base b;
    b.push_back("aB");
    b.push_back("bB");
    b.push_back("cB");
    b.run();    // prints aB bB cB

    std::cout << std::endl;

    Derived d;
    d.push_back("aD");
    d.push_back("bD");
    d.push_back("cD");
    d.run();    // prints aD bD cD

    return 0;
}
```

If so then the explanation is next: there is no such thing as a "virtual variable", but there are virtual functions. You can use virtual functions as "internal accessors" for your member variables. Although, Derived class contains both `vars_Base` and `vars_Derived`, `get_vars()` lets you override access to appropriate instance of vars.

Hope you'll find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of virtual functions to solve your problem, without the use for generics.

Here is a solution using virtual functions (applied to your sample code) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
  protected:
    void read(std::vector<std::string>);

  public:
    virtual void run() { read(vars_Base); }
    std::vector<std::string> vars_Base;
};

void Base::read(std::vector<std::string> int_vars)
{
    for (auto int_vars_it : int_vars)
    {
        std::cout << int_vars_it << "\n";
    }
}

class Derived : public Base
{
  protected:
  public:
    void run() override { read(vars_Derived); } 
    std::vector<std::string> vars_Derived;
    ///Here are other functions only known to Derived, not Base
};

int main()
{
    Base b;
    b.vars_Base.push_back("aB");
    b.vars_Base.push_back("bB");
    b.vars_Base.push_back("cB");
    b.run();

    Derived d;
    d.vars_Derived.push_back("aD");
    d.vars_Derived.push_back("bD");
    d.vars_Derived.push_back("cD");
    d.run();

    return 0;
}
```

This solution allows to encapsulate vars_Base and vars_Derived inside the classes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To improve the encapsulation, it should be better to put vars_Base in the private section of the Base class